# Why aren't Grobner bases more common?

Tags: numerical-analysis, computer-algebra

I have only heard of / seen Grobner bases in passing, but my understanding is that they are much like vector bases but for polynomials instead of linear systems. I know polynomials are used in CAD and graphics at the very least. Is there any particular reason why I haven't seen Grobner bases in application? I'm trying to determine whether they are worth the time to learn for my own work.

Edit: I should probably have specified that my use for them would be in solving algebraic systems. I'm mainly wondering how they compare to numerical solution techniques such as Newton's method, and other more linearization/derivative based methods. I'm an interested in any use case, but especially in this one.

Comment: Finding a Gröbner basis sometimes takes a lot of time, which limits their usefulness.

Comment: What should drive your choice are the ways they can be useful to you. Take a looks at [some of the uses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis#Properties_and_applications_of_Gr%C3%B6bner_bases) and see if you have a current need for those. They certainly are very useful, since they play the same as polynomial long division, in the case of several variables. Also, learning how to compute them is not much harder than polynomial long division, after you learn how to replace the way you order monomials in  one variable for the case of several variables.

Comment: I think the main difference between Newton's method and the applications of Groebner bases is that the first is a local method. It will give you local information, like finding one solution. Through the use of Groebner basis you can aim to get global information. For example, the computation of the dimension of set of solutions, the [genus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_(mathematics)) of the set of solutions or other topological properties, or compute a [resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_of_singularities) and obtain a parametrization of the set of solutions.

Comment: @plop That makes a lot of sense. So, that's a point in Groebner's favor. Is Newton just faster?

Comment: Well, Groebner basis is not an algorithm. It is, to put it in the language of systems of equations, an equivalent form in which you can re-write your system, like echelon form, for linear systems. Newton's method is an algorithm and its goal is to find **a** solution. You could have algorithms that aim to find solutions of a system of equations that first put  the system in this "Groebner basis form" and then take advantage of that form to produce solutions, potentially all solutions.

Comment: Just as a side note, you're probably going to see Gröbner bases turn up more in the world of post-quantum cryptography.

Comment: @Pseudonym Although not really related to my question, this strikes me as interesting and I'd appreciate any sources that you could provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't know what you expect to get as an answer, but in the comments you already got that if you haven't seen them used is due to two reasons.

1. The main one is probably that maybe you haven't had the need to solve problems in which they are needed, yet, and
2. that the problems, like finding **a** solution of a system of polynomial equations. are more efficiently done by algorithms that target exactly that problem, like Newton's method. Groebner bases [can end up with large degrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buchberger%27s_algorithm#Complexity) for systems with relatively few variables and degrees larger than one.

---

The usefulness of Groebner bases becomes clear once you study what they are. They are  a form in which to put a system of equations. The form is canonical once you fix a way to [order monomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomial_order) in several variables. If you have seen some commutative algebra, Groebner bases are a canonical set of generators of ideals in a polynomial ring $I\subset R=K[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n]$.

When you choose a [convenient monomial order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomial_order#Lexicographic_order) it happens that the form has the same property as the [row echelon form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form) for linear system of equations, that the equations have less and less variables until eventually (for a system that has finitely many solutions) the last equation is a polynomial in one variables. So, incidentally you get out of it a method to find **all** solutions by backward substitution. You find all solutions of this polynomial in one variable, by either Newton's method, or [perhaps some method that finds them all roots at once](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durand%E2%80%93Kerner_method). This gives you the possible values of one of the variables. Then you substitute these values in the previous equations and repeat the process with them. See [here](http://www.kalkbrener.at/Selected_publications_files/Kalkbrener87.pdf) for one way to do these steps.

**Example:** For the system $$\begin{align}x^2+y^2-1&=0\\xy-4&=0\end{align}$$
you get $$\begin{align}4x+y^3-y&=0\\y^4-y^2+16&=0\end{align}$$
Try it with [Singular](https://www.singular.uni-kl.de:8003/), by inputting

```
// Define the ring R[x,y] of polynomials in variables x,y; 
// and lexicographical ordering to order monomials.;
ring r = 0,(x,y),lp; 
// The ideal generated by those two polynomials. ;
ideal I =(x^2+y^2-1,x*y-4);
// The same ideal, but now generated by its Groebner basis.;
ideal GI=groebner(I);
// Print it.;
GI;
```

As you see, Groebner basis is not an algorithm, but a form for a system, and its goal is not to find one solution, but to put the system in a form that helps compute properties of the set of solutions as a whole. Modulo technicalities, the set of solutions is called an [algebraic variety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_variety). Problems that you might need to solve could be, for example,

1. What is the **intersection** of algebraic varieties? More explicitly, suppose you have a mechanical arm with both ends attached to two fixed points and having two or three elbows (joints). What are the positions that these elbows can be? It is an algebraic variety that can be described first as the intersection of the equations that you get by imposing the length of each segment of the arm and the condition on the fixed points at each end.
2. **Parametrization** of algebraic varieties. If the mechanical arm above had only one elbow, its positions would be a circle. Perhaps you know that $t\mapsto (\cos(t),\sin(t))$ parametrizes a circle, when $t\in[0,2\pi)$, but it could be better to get a rational parametrization, like $t\mapsto(\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2},\frac{2t}{1+t^2})$, for $t\in[-\infty,\infty]$. Such parametrizations always exist. You compute them by an algorithm that uses Groebner bases among other things.
3. Maybe you need the inverse problem of (2), **implicitization**. You want a robot arm that can cut this shape that the design team chose for the silhouette of a car. They sure like their [Bezier curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve). They happen to be algebraic.
4. You want your computer to discover the proofs of all synthetic geometry problems that you did in high school. After sufficient squaring, the hypotheses and the thesis are polynomial equations. So, you only need to check that the first can reduce the latter to $0=0$. This a particular case of problem (1).

Comment: This will do - the examples were helpful. Thanks for your repeated help.